# How to get Text of the direct element without all sub-node text

Tags: java, regex, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
<li class="lvprice prc">
    <span class="bold">
    $252.00
        <div class="medprc">
            <span class="prcVS">Trending at</span>
            <span class="median">
            $259.85
```

Also, [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YROO7.png).
 [image]

I want to `getText` such that it returns "$252.00"
Currently, `getText` returns "$252.00 Trending at $259.85".
So it's getting text from the direct element, and it's also including text for sub-nodes.

I'm currently using `findElements(By.cssSelector("li.lvprice.prc"))`

I looked into `WebElement.getText()` documentation. It's built to grab all subnode text as well.

I could use regex to only grab the 252.00 from the string, but I'm not sure that's the most professional way.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the entire text and than remove the children text

```
String allText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.lvprice.prc")).getText();
String childrenText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.medprc")).getText();
String parentText = allText.replace(childrenText, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li class="lvprice prc">
    <span class="bold">.*?(\$\d+.?\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mY3cT6/1)